# MATLAB curve-fitting with a custom equation: fittype error

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, least-squares

I created a class in MATLAB which defines a custom equation to use for fitting a set of data points. This class is supposed to represent an asymmetric equation, where the left side of the peak is independent of the right side ([example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dG4Sa.gif)).

The static method below works when I use it in the string to create a `fittype` object:

```
function Y = AsymmCutoff(x, side, xdata)
        numPts=length(xdata);
        step = zeros(1,numPts);
        if side == 1
            for i=1:numPts
                if xdata(i) < x
                    step(i)=1;
                else
                    step(i)=0;
                end
            end
        elseif side == 2
            for i=1:numPts
                if xdata(i) < x
                    step(i)=0;
                else
                    step(i)=1;
                end
            end
        end
        Y=step';
        end
```

For a 1xN array of data points specified by `xdata`, the function above returns a Nx1 column array of 0's and 1's, depending on whether you want the left side (`peak = 1`) or the right side (`peak = 2`) of the peak. The peak position is specified by the argument `x`.

Not surprisingly, I found that it took a significant amount of time to iterate through the for loops after running the profiler, so I rewrote it as below:

```
function Y = AsymmCutoff(x, side, xdata)
    if side == 1
        step = xdata < x;
    elseif side == 2
        step = xdata > x;
    end
    Y=step';
    end
```

However, even though they output the same size `Y`, Matlab throws me this error even though the rest of my code stayed the same:

```
Custom equations must produce an output vector, matrix, or array that is the same size and shape as the input data. This custom equation fails to meet that requirement.
```

Just to be sure, I double checked that it was this function that was giving me the error by switching back and forth between the two different versions. As expected, the original function worked and the new function threw an error.

Can anyone explain to me why?

Comment: What do you finally try to fit? `Y .* xdata` ?